# Rounding off a number to the nearest integer even if it is below 0.5 for example 1.2 to become 2 in java

Tags: java, math

I want to round a number up even if it is less than **0.5**.

In java, for example using the `Math.round()` it rounds up **0.5** to **1** while rounds down **0.4** to **0**.

I want 0.4 also to be rounded up to 1.

**Expected Outcomes:**

```
Input : 1.2, Output : 2

Input 1.1, Output : 2
```

Comment: Be careful with your tags. Your Question has nothing to do with Spring, nor processor cores. I deleted the irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 3):

## Ceiling

Use [`Math.ceil( 0.4 )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)). The name is [ceiling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), not rounding.